# Kubernetes (Minikube): environment variable

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I'm running a simple spring microservice project with Minikube. I have two projects: lucky-word-client (on port 8080) and lucky-word-server (on port 8888). lucky-word-client has to communicate with lucky-word-server. I want to inject the static Nodeport of lucky-word-server (http://192.***.**.100:32002) as an environment variable in my Kuberenetes deployment script of lucky-word-client. How I could do?

This is deployment of lucky-word-server:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lucky-server
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: lucky-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lucky-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: lucky-server
          image: lucky-server-img
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8888
```

This is the service of lucky-word-server:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: lucky-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: lucky-server
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8888
    port: 80
    nodePort: 32002
  type: NodePort
```

This is the deployment of lucky-word-client:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lucky-client
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: lucky-client
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lucky-client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: lucky-client
          image: lucky-client-img
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

This is the service of lucky-word-client:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: lucky-client
spec:
  selector:
    app: lucky-client
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    port: 80
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: also please don't use tags like "google-kubernetes-engine" and "kubernetes-ingress" unless your question is about these.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes automatically injects services as environment variables. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables

**But you should not use this.** This won't work unless all the services are in place when you create the pod. It is inspired by "docker" which also moved on to DNS based service discovery now. So "environment based service discovery" is a thing of the past.

Please rely on DNS service discovery. Minikube ships with `kube-dns` so you can just use the `lucky-server` hostname (or one of `lucky-server[.default[.svc[.cluster[.local]]]]` names). Read the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/